# Django Annotate с OneToMany

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

У менять есть две модели, упростил их для примера:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    total_price = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def current_status(self):
        """
        current status == last status
        :return: TaskStatus
        """
        return self.statuses.order_by('-date').first()


class OrderStatus(models.Model):     
    ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('new', 'Новый'),
        ('in_progress', 'В процессе'),
    )
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='statuses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES)
```

Теперь бы я хотел получить заказы, у которых `current_status` равняется `new`.

В идеале, хочется написать так:

```
Order.objects.filter(current_status__status='new').all()
```

Но Django не умеет так. Поэтому хотелось бы `current_status` прицепить к выборке заказов как аннотацию, т.е.

```
Order.objects.annotate(current_status=<какой-то код>).filter(current_status='new')
```

Как все это оформить максимально эффективно и красиво?

Comment: Непонятны причины, по которым у вас статус вынесен в отдельную модель. Что мешало поле `status` сделать в `Order`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev история статусов, дата присвоения, менеджер который присвоил статус и т.п.

Comment: Вам стоит очень серьёзно подумать о необходимости такого решения, оно сильно усложнит вам жизнь. Может проще использовать что-нибудь вроде django-reversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам может помочь [подзапрос](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

statuses = OrderStatus.objects.filter(order=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')
order = (Order.objects
              .annotate(current_status=Subquery(statuses.values('status')[:1]))
              .filter(current_status='new'))
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало! Если у кого-то будет аналогичная проблема - не забывайте удалить свой кастомный current_status (@property), иначе будут ошибки.